# Flowchart horizontal alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I locally define the local horizontal text alignment?
In the example below I would like the word TITLE to be centered and the rest of the text with the usual justified (text distributed between the margins).

How can I move horizontally the flowcharts to the page center?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}           \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}                

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}
% Define block styles
\tikzset{
block/.style={
rectangle,
draw,
text width=20em,
text centered,
rounded corners
},
descr/.style={
fill=white,
inner sep=2.5pt
},
connector/.style={
-latex,
font=\scriptsize
},
rectangle connector/.style={
connector,
to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
pos=0.5
},
rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
straight connector/.style={
connector,
to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center,     nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text text text text
}               &  \\
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text
}               &  \\                                              
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text 
}               &  \\                                              
};
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The psd_thesis.cls is reported below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{psd_thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Double-spaced

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bib style

%\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
%\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}  

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\large \scshape \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \scshape \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}  

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}% % the name{1}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{3.0\baselineskip}% % the before skip{2.5\baselineskip}%    % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}% % the name
{2}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{-\baselineskip}% % the before  skip{1.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\endinput
```

Comment: `\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}`?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I already tried it but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, without use of `matrix` library ...

In such simple case as is your flowchart, the use TikZ library `chains` is very effective way (to my opinion, the best) to draw flowcharts:

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm,
      start chain = A going below,
block/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
              text width=20em, align=justify,
              on chain=A, join=by -latex
              },
                        ]
\node[block]    {\hfil  TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE\\% this works for one line title
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     
                 text text text text text};
\node[block]    {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
                        MULTILINE TITLE MULTILINE TITLE MULTILINE TITLE 
                        }\\[1.5ex]                    % in case of multi line title
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\node[block]    {\hfil  TITLE \\
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     
                 text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Added package `showframe` serves only to show page layout and that you can see, that flowchart is centered in text field. In formatting of text in nodes I understand, that text in it should be justified (as is other text in document), only title should be centered. I show two ways, how to center only a "title" of node: if it is in single line or if it is multi lined.

**Addendum:**
For add a caption, you need to put flowchart into `figure` environment (preambe is the same as above):

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
  start chain = A going below,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                 text width=20em, align=justify,
                 on chain=A, join=by -latex
                },
                        ]
\node[block]    {\hfil  TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE\\% this works for one line title
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                 text text text text text};
\node[block]    {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
                        MULTILINE TITLE MULTILINE TITLE MULTILINE TITLE
                        }\\[1.5ex]                    % in case of multi line title
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\node[block]    {\hfil  TITLE \\
                 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                 text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my extremly important flowchart \dots}
\label{fig:flowchart}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add a caption to the flowchart?

Comment: yes, you need to put it in `figure` environment. See update of mine answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `center` environment should do, but a problem is that you have added a second column (with empty nodes) to your matrix, and because of `column sep=2cm` there is a lot of extra whitespace in the `tikzpicture`. See below where I added `draw` to the options of the `matrix`, and the `showframe` package to draw a box around the text area.

In the second `tikzpicture` I removed all the `&` from the matrix. The outer frame in the image shows the text area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show text area
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}                

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
% Define block styles
\tikzset{
block/.style={
rectangle,
draw,
text width=20em,
text centered,
rounded corners
},
descr/.style={
fill=white,
inner sep=2.5pt
},
connector/.style={
-latex,
font=\scriptsize
},
rectangle connector/.style={
connector,
to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
pos=0.5
},
rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
straight connector/.style={
connector,
to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[draw,matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center,     nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text text text text
}               &  \\
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text
}               &  \\                                              
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text 
}               &  \\                                              
};
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[draw,matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center,     nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text text text text
}                 \\
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text
}                 \\                                              
|[block]| {TITLE \\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text 
}                 \\                                              
};
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: T.I solved the problem of the flowchart alignment adding \begine{center} and end{center} and deleting the "&".

Still remains to align the "text..." with justified alignment. Thank you.

Comment: @Luca Set `text width=\textwidth` in the `block` style?